# A person who is trying to impress somebody

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What do we call a person who is trying to impress somebody **(not necessarily to gain any advantage)**. For example, he buys them expensive products, always talking in a sweet manner etc.

To describe an act of such a person, I want to say the following sentence.

> Well, I think he is just being ____________.

Is "Pretentious" a suitable word to fill in the blank in above sentence? What are other choices of word?

Comment: The closest idiomatic way to say this I can think of would be simply "...he's just trying to impress"

Comment: **A sycophant** is the polite word for an ass-kisser.

Comment: @Lambie That looks like a good answer to me :)

Comment: @Joachim Thanks. Yeah, too bad I was so late to the game. :)

Comment: @Lambie I'm even later, but posted an answer nonetheless :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flashy /jazzy or gimmicky,
___ an outward show to impress.

Answer (score 2):

- As an adjective you might want to consider '[ostentatious](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ostentatious)':

  > - characterized by or given to pretentious or conspicuous show in an attempt to impress others
  > - *(of actions, manner, qualities exhibited, etc.)* intended to attract notice

  A more well-known alternative is '[pompous](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pompous)', but it doesn't necessarily mean someone is attempting to impress others, and could just mean someone is "full of themselves".
- As a noun you could opt for '[boaster](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/boaster)':

  > a person who boasts or brags.

  Synonyms include '[blowhard](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/blowhard)' or '[windbag](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/windbag)'.

  As suggested in the comments by [Lambie](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252956/a-person-who-is-trying-to-impress-somebody/602795?noredirect=1#comment1519511_252956), the word '[sycophant](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sycophant)' comes very close, as well:

  > a self-seeking, servile flatterer; fawning parasite.

  Note, though, how this is used explicitly for the kind of flattering done to gain an advantage.

  Finally, the term '[braggadocio](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/braggadocio)'—which sounds boastful in and of itself—refers to the action of the braggart:

  > empty boasting; bragging.

Comment: braggadocio is not the person, luv. It's the action. Why not add my term so I don't have to write an answer? :)

Comment: @Lambie Thank you, added! Dictionary.com's entry for 'braggadocio' mentions it can be both: have you found this is not the case?

Comment: Yeah, I always thought it was the action of a braggart. Ha ha. :)

Answer (score 0):

Partly depends on the motive for the behaviour

Insincere 
Ingratiating - implies he wants advantage

Deferential - implies he sees himself as inferior, like a servant

Disarming - more neutral in tone

Beguiling, captivating, charming - positive in tone.

Pretentious has a meaning of trying to be socially or intellectually superior.

Answer (score 0):

a brown-noser, a kiss-ass or an ass-kisser, a butt-kisser, a suck-up

Comment: All these words can be used only in cases where the person is trying to impress in order to curry favour. The OP said that it needn't be so.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Leslie. This could be a good answer. Perhaps you could cite the resources you used to define your selections, then test them in a sentence that resembles the example of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps affectation is what you're looking for?

noun: speech or conduct not natural to oneself : an unnatural form of behavior meant especially to impress others

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affectation

Answer (score 0):

A flatterer is someone who praises another without being sincere.  The purpose is to benefit the flatterer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A [simp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simp), to use the parlance of our times.