# Common term or single word for someone who is embarrassingly over-complimentary

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, vocabulary

Does English have a word for someone who compliments another person in a way which is awkward or even embarrassing?

Someone who uses compliments which are overly-familiar and all but inappropriate, and praises someone they barely know in over-the-top fashion?

Comment: The most common adjective used here is [*fulsome*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fulsome). *Fulsome compliments* is almost a cliché.

Comment: I nominate _[effusive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effusive)_: "marked by the expression of great or excessive emotion or enthusiasm," according to Merriam-Webster.

Comment: I might use a simple one - assenting

Comment: So you're looking for a synonym for "bar patron"?

Comment: So the compliments clearly aren't genuine, right?

Comment: You can stand here all day blowing sunshine up my ass, or you can tell me what you're after.

Comment: Very similar recent question, if not a duplicate: [(252956)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252956/a-person-who-is-trying-to-impress-somebody/)

Answer (score 47):

**Fawning**

From the [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fawning):

> adjective
>
> Displaying exaggerated flattery or affection; obsequious:

Example:

> 'fawning interviews with Hollywood celebs'

Answer (score 28):

As touched upon in a previous answer, ***[obsequious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/obsequious)*** fits the bill somewhat.

> Full of or exhibiting servile compliance; fawning.

thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 21):

I'm fond of “unctuous” :

> **unctuous**
>
> Excessively flattering or ingratiating; oily: *he seemed anxious to please but not in an unctuous way*

from the [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unctuous)

Answer (score 16):

sycophant -- a person who praises powerful people in order to get their approval

Comment: A good word choice, @anon777. If you add examples and citations (see some of the other answers), I am sure you will see more upvotes for 'sycophant'.

Answer (score 15):

**[Toady](https://www.google.com/search?q=Toady%20definition)**.

> noun
>   1. a person who behaves obsequiously to someone important.

(Google)

For example: *The governor surrounded herself with toadies who ensured a constant stream of sunshine flowed up the gubernatorial anus.*

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). Toady is a good suggestion, but the answer would be even better if you included the source of the usage example. If you throw in a dictionary definition (with a reference), even better ;-).

Comment: Thanks. Really, posters are expected to look up an example and cite for basic vocabulary and a sentence?  Something about burden of proof is off in that model.  I don't want to win the answer contest, just help someone find a word. I get it for a point of fact, but vocabulary? I am not trying to be rude, just trying to understand how this place works.

Comment: It isn't obligatory, but it's recommended (it may depend on the sort or question you are answering, but yes it does apply to vocabulary questions). If the sentence you gave is your own, than it's OK, but if it's someone else's than [attributing their work](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) is obligatory. For more information on how the site works you can check out the [help centre](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) and [meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/). Or look for the most upvoted answers under the tag of your interest :-)

Comment: Sometimes the word suggested needs no backup, no support it is so well-known and commonplace it would be silly to quote from a dictionary. But some words are slang, colloquial, only used in America, or in Australia, for example, in those cases it is *helpful* to leave a link, or provide a brief explanation or clarification. Many users on the site are not native speakers, while some of us  are ex-pats missing from the homeland for decades, and are unfamiliar with new phrases. So, think of these poor souls when they see a word that means a frog, but is used to describe a flatterer.

Comment: I think it is a good answer though so have made the suggested edits. I hope that's ok with you Nenagh. Please feel free to roll them back if not.

Answer (score 10):

> **effusive**
>
> uttered with unrestrained enthusiasm

**Profuse; overflowing: *[effusive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/effusive)* *praise*.**

(TFD)

Answer (score 9):

**Gushing**

> adjective
>
> (Of speech or writing) effusive or exaggeratedly enthusiastic: gushing praise

See the [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gushing).

Comment: @tchrist there was a new member who used to post three answers, quite regularly in SWR, and nobody ever left a similar comment. I'm sure on meta there are topics encouraging users to submit  *different* answers in separate posts. **Two** different answers are not rep-hounding/whoring, but anything over three would be, I'd agree, dangerously close.

Comment: @tchrist There was a meta question posted about this just yesterday: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6969/word-request-answers-one-answer-per-word

Comment: I hate when a SWR answer has more than *one* suggestion. How are we supposed to vote on that? Many a time I have said, *I would upvote this but for the other two (or more).* Not that I've never done it, as there seems to be no rule about it one way or another.

Answer (score 6):

I see the adjective tag, but for me "a single word for someone" calls for a noun (otherwise you have adjective + "person"). So, my suggestions are:

**[adulator](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/adulate?q=adulator#adulate__12)**

> *That many in the eighteenth century actively resisted what seemed to them classical cultural imperialism, something supported by contemporaries they considered spineless adulators and imitators, may be less widely understood.*
>
> *No one likes a smarmy adulator*

derived from

to adulate

> Praise (someone) excessively (ODO)

or you could use:

**[flatterer](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flatterer)**

> A person who lavishes praise, often insincerely; a sycophant:
>
> *he is not allowing flatterers to deceive him*

If you insist on an adjective then the above mentioned:

[smarmy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smarmy):

> behaving in a way that seems polite, kind, or pleasing but is not genuine or believable (M-W)

might fit.

Comment: Agreed -- the question is clearly asking for a noun, not an adjective.

Answer (score 5):

For the special case when such compliments are part of an ulterior motive: A *kiss-ass*, alternately *ass-kisser*, is a person who excessively praises a superior with the (perhaps only perceived) intention of gaining favor for personal advancement. This pejorative term would likely be used by such a person's colleagues, who are disgruntled by the unseemly competition.

Similar terms include *brown-noser*, *suck-up*, and arguably *teacher's pet* (when the person is a student and their lauded superior is their teacher).

Answer (score 2):

You might describe this person as having a [cloying](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+cloying) personality:

> cloy: disgust or sicken (someone) with an excess of sweetness, richness, or sentiment.

Answer (score 1):

> kiss-up (plural kiss-ups)
>
> (colloquial) One who flatters a supervisor, or superior, in order to
>   get special attention Joe got that promotion because he was a kiss-up,
>   not because he knew the job.

Wiktionary