# Adjective for "impressive without seeming to try very hard"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Consider a movie which is good while having a natural, effortless feel to it as opposed to overuse of special effects and whatnot.

There is [a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252956/a-person-who-is-trying-to-impress-somebody) looking for a kind of opposite to the word I'm looking for. The accepted answer there lists "flashy", "jazzy", and "gimmicky". I'm looking for an adjective describing a real good, definitely not boring thing which is at the same time none of those.

---

Added from comments:

Any kind of object which can be impressive without seeming to try very hard (or having designers who tried very hard) could be meant, I guess. *Natural* is not specific enough:

> Berlin Syndrome is a **natural** thriller

that doesn't really capture the meaning I need.

Comment: _Understated elegance_?

Comment: Does this apply only to movies? If not, what else can you imagine it being applied to? (By the way, I’d also like to know what’s wrong with _natural_.)

Comment: @J.R. I mostly had movies & shows in mind. But any kind of object which can be impressive without seeming to try very hard (or having designers who tried very hard) could be meant, I guess. Natural is not specific enough, "Berlin Syndrome is a natural thriller", that doesn't really capture the meaning I need.

Comment: The answer to this question interests me too. Does the word "authentic" fit well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider ***uncontrived***.

> Berlin Syndrome is an ***uncontrived*** thriller

ODO:

> **[uncontrived](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/uncontrived)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> Not appearing artificial.
>
> ‘Some have praised the film for its uncontrived, natural feel.’

Answer (score 3):

Since *flashy* is the opposite of what you want, you can start searching from ***unflashy***, and then move onto its synonyms such as ***plain, unadorned, undecorated, unembellished, unornamented, unelaborate, basic, unsophisticated, no-frills; classic, understated, uncluttered, restrained, unshowy***, and pick one that fits best after checking the definitions in a dictionary of your choice.

Just an example:

***Understated*** -- [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/understated)

> (adj.) not trying to impress people or to attract their attention, and therefore attractive or effective
>   *She dressed with understated elegance.*

Comment: Understated goes in a good direction. I tend to dislike some of the others, "unsophisticated" for example is just a negation of the (usually positive) "sophisticated", where I'm not sure that a thing which has effortless elegance can't, at the same time, be sophisticated.

Comment: Quietly compelling, well-paced, even enthralling.  Unobtrusively holds our attention.

Answer (score 3):

You use the word **effortless** in your question;  but as far as I can tell it actually answers your question.  The OED definition is:

> Acting without effort; unstrained, easy.

This is often applied to a situation in which someone makes something "seem easy", without unnaturalness or artifice;  it does not necessarily imply that no effort was exerted:

> Dutch children’s theater company Het Laagland presents this formally innovative, **effortlessly thrilling** piece of physical theater about rediscovering the joys of play, shaking off the shackles of adulthood, and flying high with the king of make-believe.

[(Brooklyn Academy of Music website)](http://www.bam.org/kids/2017/the-peter-pan-experience)

> In the end, the comic’s best trick is the illusion that comedy is **effortless.** That people imagine what he’s doing is easy is an occupational hazard. Cary Grant never won an Oscar, primarily, I suspect, because he made everything look so **effortless.** Why reward someone for having fun, for being charming?

[(Richard Russo interview on failbetter.com)](http://www.failbetter.com/04/Russo.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I like the term understated, but "low-key" is perhaps slightly more complimentary or "cool".

> **Low-key**
> [loh-kee]
> adjective, Also, low-keyed
>
> 1. of reduced intensity; restrained; understated.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/low--key)

Comment: +1 I'm up all night to get **[loki](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XYIeJn6L58)**. It really is 'cool'. I hear it in hiphop song lyrics sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

> **Well-proportioned**
> /adjective (well proportioned when postpositive)
>
> 1. having the correct or desirable relationship between constituent parts with respect to size, number, or degree
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/well-proportioned)

This term is perhaps a bit less diminutive than the other terms. It is more focused establishing an ideal balance.