# What is the meaning of 'choffer'?

Tags: meaning, etymology

While looking into [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252956) asking for a word for someone who tries to impress another, I kept thinking of something I heard in the video game Dishonored:

> Blow off, choffer!

It is used as a randomized reaction by the NPCs. I've always interpreted 'choffer' to be synonymous to 'boaster', but this was apparently only based on the usage in the game, since I cannot find a suitable meaning for it (online, at least).

Merriam-Webster gives as [its definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/choffer):

> a portable heater or chafing dish

Then there is the similar sounding (and indubitably related) word '[chauffer](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/chauffer)':

> a small, portable stove.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/choffer) also suggests an etymology related to both 'chauffer' and '[chauffeur](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/chauffeur)', but they don't seem to really fit the dialogue.
I can imagine how someone who is full of hot air is referred to as a stove, since [hot air](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hot-air) carries the meaning "*empty, exaggerated, or pretentious talk or writing*", but AFAIK the word 'chauffer' is too obscure to have that association come about freely.

[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Choffer) has a more fitting definition, but this could actually have been influenced by the game itself: "*a general term meaning a person who is a dick, a douchebag, a jerk, or someone who has done something stupid.*"

The most logical  explanation was found on Reddit, [a user mentioning](https://www.reddit.com/r/dishonored/comments/1szj44/comment/ce2txio/) it could be a made-up word to establish a cultural distinction for increased immersion (perhaps inspired by the word 'taffer' as an alternative for 'thief' in the video game of that name).

But then I came upon someone on the [Steam forums](https://steamcommunity.com/app/205100/discussions/0/828925849328708317/) comparing it to "yarn choffer", which apparently is "*Old English slang for someone who tells "tall tales"*". I can't find that definition elsewhere.

**Can someone clue me in on the etymology and/or meaning of the word "choffer"?**

Comment: Google Books has hundreds if not thousands of instances of "**yarn spinner**", but they don't have even a *single* instance of "**yarn choffer**" (in **40 million books** now scanned?), so I don't think there's much point in speculating about an etymology for **yarn choffer** that predates the Internet.

Comment: [Chuffer](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED7697) seems like a pretty good match, but I have no explanation for how it could have found its way into the game.

Comment: Is it possible they’re saying *chuffer*? COCA shows *What's that pasty-faced chuffer want?* from the 1997 movie *The Full Monty*, and the OED says: *[obsolete, rare] Apparently: deceiver, cheat, impostor.*

Comment: @Laurel & TinfoilHat That's an excellent find! I think the subtitles in the game spell it as "choffer", but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I rather doubt that this is a possibility, but it’s slightly interesting  . . .

There’s a fish — [*Lagodon rhomboides*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagodon) — whose common names include pinfish, pin perch, sand perch, **choffer**, and butterfish.

I learned this from [a post in the ScubaBoard forum](https://scubaboard.com/community/threads/choffer-real-name.162295/):

> Around Florida, there’s a kind of baitfish which hangs around marinas
> and docks that we Southern folk call choffer. They’re good baitfish.
> However, I’ve never seen “choffer” referred to in any encyclopedia or
> scientific article. So enlighten a Southern son of a fisherman: what’s
> the ACTUAL name of the fish that we call choffer?

I surfaced that, so to speak, by searching *choffer* minus anything to do with heating: `“choffer” -charcoal -coal -stove -heater -heating`

Anyway, the fish is of little value except as live bait.

> *Blow off, fishbait!*

Like I said, it’s a stretch. You can learn more about the choffer by searching `“pinfish” “choffer”`.

Here’s an even longer shot: A Shakespeare-inspired insult? See this:

> **chough**, *n.*
> **1.**
> **a.** A bird of the crow family; formerly applied somewhat widely to all the smaller chattering species, but especially to the common
> Jackdaw.
>  <sub>[selected usage example:] 1688    R. HOLME
> *Acad. Armory* ii. 248/1    The Jack Daw, or Daw..in some places is called a Caddesse, or Choff.</sub>
> **b.** *figurative*. Chatterer, prater.
>  <sub>a1616    W. SHAKESPEARE *Tempest* (1623) ii. i. 271    Lords, that can
> prate As amply..as this Gonzallo: I my selfe could make A Chough of as
> deepe chat.
>   Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

[Shakespeare’s Words](https://www.shakespeareswords.com/Public/Glossary.aspx?letter=c) lists three definitions for *chough*:

- chatterer, prater, prattler
- jackdaw
- rustic, clown

> *Blow off, chatterer!*

Go down that rabbit hole with a search of `“chough” “insult”`.

Lastly, is it possible that the characters are saying *chuffer* — or are saying *choffer* as a polite form of *chuffer* (cf. *damn* and *dang*)? You know what to do: `“chuffer” “insult”`

Comment: Dishonored's world *is* filled with fish and sea. For example, whaling plays a large part in the city of Dunwall, where the first game mostly takes place. I'm still not convinced, but it is a nice association and a good find!

Comment: Yeah, I imagine Dunwall is a long way from Florida!